# Unable to find the Version Control option in the quick toggle of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, ide

Unable to find the Version Control option in the quick toggle of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2. I have opened a Git repository so expecting the option to be visible here:

[image]

All I can see in the VCS menu is this:

[image]

How do I enable it?

Comment: Are there VCS mappings set in "File | Settings | Version Control"?

Comment: That's an old issue was resolved later (possibly with an update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Git integration and setup repository.

> VCS / Enable Version Control Integration.

[image]

Comment: I could not find that option (edited my answer). I guess that's because it's already enabled?

Comment: Yes, this tool window is available if version control integration is enabled for your project. From documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window.html   You can try alt+9 , this one is more convenient

Answer (score 0):

To setup repository, you need to first Add VCS Directory Mapping.

Here's the way, Go to File-> Settings first.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried Command + 9 on Mac and it worked for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woXti.png)